# Buscar o index de uma array usando o nome do objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho o codigo abaixo de gostaria de saber como eu pego o indice do array para que eu possa remover ele do array futuramente.

mais detalhes: tenho um array onde é inserido nele de acordo com o que é preenchido o formulario, apos é imprimido uma lista cada um com um checkbox.
quando o checkbox esta marcado, eu consigo pegar o value dele.
quero usar esse value para buscar dentro do array o index equivalente daquele value.
é possivel fazer assim?

objetivo: eu quero remover do array o checkbox selecionado, se tiver uma sugestao melhor do que a minha acima.

abaixo a imagem do meu
[console do chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjCjG.png) para que possa ter mais clareza.

```js
const botaoEnviar = document.querySelector(".enviar");
let categoria = document.querySelector("#categoria");
let inputLista = document.querySelector("#txtListaCompras");
const divLista = document.getElementById("lista");
let itemsLista = [];
let arrCategoria = [];


function LiberarInput (){
    var txtListaCompras=document.querySelector("#txtListaCompras");
    var listaSuspensa=document.getElementById("categoria").value;
    if (listaSuspensa!=="nenhum"){    
        txtListaCompras.disabled=false;  
        txtListaCompras.placeholder=" Digite um item para adicionar a Lista de compras "
    }
    else{
        txtListaCompras.disabled=true; 
        txtListaCompras.placeholder=" Selecione a categoria primeiro"
    }
 }
categoria.addEventListener("click", LiberarInput)

botaoEnviar.disabled=true;
function LiberarEnviar (){
    if ((inputLista.value =="")){
        
        botaoEnviar.disabled=true;
    }
    else{
        
        botaoEnviar.disabled=false;
        
    }
}
inputLista.addEventListener ("keyup",  LiberarEnviar)

function BloquearEnvio() {
    botaoEnviar.disabled=true;
    inputLista.disabled=true;

 }
botaoEnviar.addEventListener ("click", BloquearEnvio)



function adicionaLista(){ 
    adicionarItens(inputLista.value, categoria.value);
    imprimirItens();}
    
botaoEnviar.addEventListener("click", adicionaLista )


function adicionarItens (nome, setor){
    let itens = {
        nome: nome,
        setor: setor
    }
    itemsLista.push(itens); 
    adicionarCategoria (itens.setor);
    categoria.value="";
    inputLista.value="";
}

function adicionarCategoria (cat){
    if(arrCategoria.includes(cat)==false){
        arrCategoria.push(cat);
    }
}

function removerItens (){
    let elementChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    console.log(elementChecked);
}

function imprimirItens (){
    divLista.innerHTML = "";
    for(let i=0; i<arrCategoria.length; i++){
        let criarDiv = document.createElement('div');
        criarDiv.id = arrCategoria[i];
        criarDiv.innerHTML = `<h2>${arrCategoria[i]}</h2>`;
        divLista.appendChild(criarDiv);

        itemsLista.filter((element) => {
            if (element.setor == arrCategoria[i]) {


                let itemLista = document.createElement('input');
                itemLista.className = "itensListaCompras";
                itemLista.type = 'checkbox';
                itemLista.id = `${element.nome}`;
                itemLista.value = `${element.nome}`;
                
                var listaLabel = document.createElement('label');
                listaLabel.setAttribute('for', element.nome);
                listaLabel.innerHTML = `${element.nome}`;

                let produtos = document.createElement('div');
                produtos.className="produtos";
                let localizacaoLista = document.getElementById(element.setor);
                
                localizacaoLista.appendChild(produtos);
                produtos.appendChild(itemLista);
                produtos.appendChild(listaLabel);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<p> Selecione a categoria de seu produto:</p>
                <select 
                id="categoria" >
                    <option value="nenhum"></option>
                    <option value="frutas">frutas</option>
                    <option value="Laticínios">Laticínios</option>
                    <option value="Congelados">Congelados</option>
                    <option value="Doces">Doces</option>
                     
                </select>
                <input 
                    disabled
                    id="txtListaCompras"
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder=" Digite um item para adicionar a Lista de compras" 
                    size="50">

                <button 
                class="enviar" >
                    enviar
                </button>
                <button class="excluir">
                    Excluir
                </button>
                <div id="lista">

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você está no caminho certo, apesar da sua pergunta estar um pouco ruidosa. Sugiro a leitura da definição de um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Dito isso, entendo que você já foi capaz de encontrar o elemento que escolheu no checkbox e o valor da sua propriedade. O seu problema se reduz, então, a remover um item de um vetor com base nesse valor.

Supondo que você tenha acesso à esse vetor ao mesmo tempo que você tem acesso ao valor escolhido, você pode utilizar a função [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para iterar neste vetor e encontrar o índice

```
const valor = 'c'; // Neste ponto voce já encontrou o valor
const indice = itemsLista.map(elemento => elemento.nome).indexOf(valor);
```

Neste exemplo, `itemsLista` é a variável que detém o seu vetor com todos os seus dados.

Existem outras opções, e você pode verificar uma discussão extensa sobre isso em inglês [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176908/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-object-by-its-property-in-javascript).

Finalmente, excluir esse item do vetor reduz-se a:

```
itemsLista.splice(indice, 1);
```